# Clojure defresource argument arity error with Liberator

Tags: clojure, compojure, arity, liberator

I am writing a clojure function that works fine when I am using `defn`to define it, but it throws arity error when instead I define it using `defresource`. I suspect it's something to do with the `:as-response` key that I am using but I have no clue how to fix it.
Any ideas?
My code:

```
(defn function-name []
  :allowed-methods [:get]
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :as-response (my function is here))
```

Error when using defresource: "Wrong number of args (2) passed to ... " I am passing 0 arguments which works fine using defn.

Comment: Can you provide the code with defresource?

Comment: If you think it's the `:as-response` option, you need to pass a function that takes 2 params and returns a map, as in the example in the bottom of this page: https://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/representations.html ... you can define that function inline with `(fn [d ctx] ...)` as in the example, or as the name of a function you have defined earlier, as long as it is a function that takes 2 parameters and returns the map.

Comment: @Doseke I am using exactly the same code, the only change is that instead of defn I use defresource. It works perfectly with defn but breaks when using defresource.

Comment: @DenisFuenzalida Is there a reason why it doesn't work with defresource, but the exact same code works fine with defn? I am still using :as-response in defn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defn` that you’ve defined is equivalent to

```clj
(defn function-name 
  []
  (do
    :allowed-methods 
    [:get]
    :available-media-types 
    ["application/json"]
    :as-response 
    (...)))
```

Since the value of the `do` expression is the last form in the expression — and the keywords and vectors don’t have any side effects — the function definition is equivalent to

```clj
(defn function-name 
  []
  (...))
```

What you have is a 0-parameter arity function. The `:as-response` and other keywords / vectors don’t do anything.

Looking at the [documentation](https://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/representations.html) for Liberator, the library expects a 2-parameter arity function when using `:as-response`. Also according to the [documentation on resources](https://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/doc/resource-definition.html) you only need to pass a parameter vector to `defresource` if you’d like a parameterized resource. So your resource should be defined

```clj
(defresource function-name
  :allowed-methods [:get]
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :as-response (fn [d ctx] ...))
```

Comment: Ohhh I understand it now, thank you. I rewrote it and it works now with defresource, thank you!